# An Error occurred while adding user: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am new to this,
Here I am trying to add a user to the database using JPA but the user is not saving into the database I am getting this error. May I know why and how to resolve this?

-If I remove @GeneratedValue from user model for id  and pass id manually in API request it is working but I saw so many youtube videos how to implement JPA there they are following @GenerateValue

User model

```
package model;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
}
```

method

```
 public CompletionStage<Result> addUser(Http.Request request) {
        JsonNode json = request.body().asJson();
        User user = Json.fromJson(json, User.class);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> addUser1(user));
    }

    private static Result addUser1(User user) {
        return jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
            try {
                entityManager.persist(user);
                return ok("User Added Successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return internalServerError("An Error occurred while adding user: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

API request: Body in Json

```
{
    "firstName": "Robin",
    "lastName": "karachri",
    "userName": "Robin",
    "password": "4563"
}
```

Comment: Show more of the exception, it should tell you more on why it might be failing. You might also turn on SQL logging to see the statements being issued- it is especially helpful if you are learning and need to debug what might be happening behind the scenes. @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) though requires DB support to generate the ID value and return it to JPA on the insert - verify the database you are using supports it and that your table was setup for it (how are you generating the tables?)

Comment: Please share the full exception. Maybe you just need to add entityManager.flush(); ... See my example for inserting into the DB https://github.com/ertra/play-framework-by-example/blob/master/app/dao/BookDAOImp.java